# How to debug a plugin with Xdebug?

Tags: plugin-development, debug, netbeans

I was able to install and setup quite easily NetBeans 6.9.1 and Xdebug on my local environment, based on PHP 5.3.0 (XAMPP).

My problem now is the following: if I put a breakpoint on Wordpress's index.php or other Wordpress core PHP files, NetBeans correctly stop at desired position. If instead I put a breakpoint on a plugin file, an trigger the code execution NetBeans does not stop there.

Do you known how can be solved?

**UPDATE:** More info about what I am trying to debug

Plugin is called **Vanilla Forums** and has the following file structure:

```
- plugins
  - vanilla-forums
    + assets
    + nbproject
    + templates
      admin.php
      embed.php
      functions.php
      hooks.php
      plugin.php
      sso.php
      widgets.php
```

I set the breakpoint inside a function named `vf_validate_options` defined in `functions.php`. I am sure that this function is executed, but NetBeans does not break there.

Comment: If you put a `throw new Exception('die');` statement after the line of the breakpoint, does it then stop (in the meaning that this kills/ends your request)?

Comment: @hakre Yes, it throws the exception (I am sure that the code where the breakpoint is set is executed)

Comment: @drake: Please take a look into the backtrace of that exception (xdebug gives you a nice one). The interesting part is if that code is still part of a file or not (you see it on the right, file and line).

Comment: @Drake: Is this code executed in the main page, or in an Ajax call? I believe [the Xdebug debugger must be enabled](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/remote) with some GET or POST variables and then sets a cookie, maybe it is not enabled for the Ajax request?

Comment: @Jan This code is executed inside Wordpress administation area. Plugin creates a link into administration left sidebar. I click that link, the plugin present me a textbox and a submit button. The code is executed when I press that submit button. Maybe it could be Ajax related problem, I will check the link in your comment.

Comment: I have the exact same problem and still can't find a fix! I'm using nusphere phped but I tried Eclipse too with no results!
The only file that xdebug stop on the breakpoint is are the wordpress "core" files. Neither the theme's php file are debugable!
Let me know if you find a solution, I made a post on the wordpress official forum with no replies:(

Comment: I think Jan Fabry is onto the solution.  I prefer to use the Firefox plugin [EasyXdebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-xdebug/), which will add the `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` query parameter to all requests.

Comment: I'd love to know if this ever had an answer, because here in 2021 I'm having exactly this issue. Break points work fine in the wordpress code, but not in the plugin code.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy solution with a Firebox extension [Xdebug Helper by Brian Gilbert](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xdebug-helper-for-firefox/). This sets cookies for the `xdebug` session which allows you to use `xdebug` within your WordPress plugins.

There are also extensions for Chrome, Safari and Opera.  The links can be found on the [xdebug website](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote)

Answer (score 1):

You've followed these instructions right?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Testing_WordPress_Performance

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@Drake:**

Stupid question, I know, but have you *"activated"* the plugin?  That's where I trip up when plugins are not being debugged.

Comment: Yes, plugin is activated. What am I trying to debug is a function trigger by a menu created by plugin self in administrator area.

Comment: @Drake - What is a *"function trigger?"*  Can you please post your code as an update to your question?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to debug the plugin's files. The only way I found for debug wordpress is to use nusphere phped wich is , unfortunately, not freeware.
That seems the only one can do that, I don't know why but I spend very long time figuring how to debug with netbeans and eclipse...with no results!

Answer (score -3):

Well, since WordPress itself provides `WP_DEBUG`, and `wp_die($msg)` ... why whould you need to debug with Xdebug? Unless you are building your plugin using a framework?

Comment: xdebug offers many tools that WP_DEBUG and output don't - profiling and stepping through code for a start...

Comment: Agreed, at the time I had very little knowledge regarding Xdebug.